# How to stop Visual Studio/msbuild from recompiling TypeScript when there are no changes

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, compilation, incremental-build

I have a c# MVC project with a fair amount of TypeScript source, which takes around 5 seconds to compile. Whenever we build the project, the TypeScript recompiles, even if nothing has changed (e.g. a referenced assembly changes, so the c# needs to recompile, but this shouldn't force the TypeScript to recompile).

Is there a way to make it so TypeScript compilation is skipped if nothing changes?

Answer (score 0):

visual studio does not support TypeScript compiler option named –watch, which run the compiler in watch mode. Watch input files and trigger recompilation on changes. For more information, please refer to:

[image]

[image]

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I'm not sure the '--watch' option is really what we want, we just don't want it to recompile if no files changed. E.g. when you build c# and no .cs files changed, it knows, but it doesn't have to 'watch' the .cs files.